# dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _vio_blocking

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I am working on old Rails project. And when I type `rake db:create` I am getting following error message:

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _vio_blocking
Referenced from: /Users/reboot/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/mysqlplus-0.1.2/lib/mysql.bundle
Expected in: flat namespace

dyld: Symbol not found: _vio_blocking
Referenced from: /Users/reboot/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/mysqlplus-0.1.2/lib/mysql.bundle
Expected in: flat namespace
```

I don't know how to solve this problem.

Below are some details about project.

- Ruby 1.8.7
- Rails 2.3.18
- DB mysql

Gems

- "will_paginate"
- "daemons"
- "json"
- "mysqlplus"
- "RedCloth"
- "newrelic_rpm"

Path on `.zshrc` file

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
```

Path set by `.rvm`

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin"
```